# Select latest row by uniqueidentifier primary key

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table like this:

| PrimaryKey | ForeignKey | OtherCol |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11C01524-C823-41F0-BBBF-08D600E1F775 | 576283C2-7F95-4697-BD4C-00006D50063A | 21 |
| 7C85E579-CA50-48BE-2E52-08D6ED60ECAB | 576283C2-7F95-4697-BD4C-00006D50063A | 18 |
| DF115856-1521-4AE6-B0BC-08D596BD6D75 | 576283C2-7F95-4697-BD4C-00006D50063A | 32 |
| 28D9FCF6-A8B2-44F5-2188-08D6E95E0D9A | E1FD7854-A8CA-4683-B43C-0001466178E1 | 2 |
| F13713D9-DE41-4199-0DD5-08D811D1252E | E1FD7854-A8CA-4683-B43C-0001466178E1 | 45 |

I need to select the last inserted row by foreign key. I try to use EF Core like this:

```
_db.MyTable.Where(x => x.ForeignKey == foreignKey)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.PrimaryKey)
           .FirstOrDefault();
```

or this query in Dapper

```
SELECT MAX(PrimaryKey) PrimaryKey, ForeignKey
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY ForeignKey
```

Can I be sure that any of this will always give me the last inserted row? Or there are other ways?

Comment: That will never give you the latest row... you need to be using a date column or similar to know which was most recently added.

Comment: Have you checked this - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53071/how-to-extract-the-last-inserted-row-in-sql-server or - https://mostafaelmasry.com/2016/05/09/how-to-find-the-last-inserted-record-in-sql-server/